# Twitter Module with Formatted tweet

Tags: 7, social-network

I use the [Twitter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) to create a feed from various accounts for my website.

If I created a block with a field `Twitter: Formatted tweet`, the preview doesn't show anything. A broken image, a blank message etc.

If I add also the field `Twitter: Twitter status message ID`, the preview show most of the tweets, but there are still some of them without content.

If I set the fields custom without the Formatted tweet, I don't have this problem.

Also, I have this error on the page where I show this block:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 146 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 157 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 11 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 12 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 35 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 38 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 41 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 146 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 157 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 11 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 12 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 35 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 38 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 41 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 146 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in twitter_views_handler_field_formatted_tweet->render() (line 157 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter_views_field_handlers.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 10 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 11 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 12 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 21 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 25 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 35 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 38 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$twitter_id in include() (line 41 of /var/lib/openshift/54f9b83bfcf933c2b800009a/app-root/data/sites/all/modules/twitter/tweet.tpl.php).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna give you an answer that will not sound like good news. The rendering of the **Twitter: Formatted tweet** field is a bit buggy at times.

As a quick workaround I'd says don't use **Twitter: Formatted tweet** and use all the other **Twitter: .........** fields available to you. And then style your output which ever way suits you with a template.

The alternative is to debug the module...

Comment: Ouch! That wasn't good! Thank you for your answer. At least I can take the css of the tweets that works and do it by myself on custom fields.